# Find all rows which match substring, with moor / moor_flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-moor

I want to select all rows which match a substring with moor / moor_flutter.

In SQL, you'd do something like this:

```
'SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE [field] LIKE '%[substring]%'
```

Is there a 'moor-like' way of doing this?

The closest I've come, is this:

```
Stream<List<Task>> watchTable() {
  return (select(tableItem)..where((tbl) => CustomExpression<bool>("field LIKE '%substring%'"))).watch();
}
```

But unfortunately that's not a nice typesafe / moor-like way.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example what I have done for **like** query:

```
  // Get all the doctors [by optional params city and area]
  Future<List<DoctorMaster>> getAllDoctors({String city = "", String area = ""}) {
    return (select(doctorMasters)..where((tbl) => tbl.city.like(city) & tbl.area.like(area))).get();
  }
```

You can do something like that for your purpose.

```
Stream<List<Task>> watchTable() {
  return (select(tableItem)..where((tbl) => tbl.yourField.like('%substring%'))).watch();
}
```

Hope it will work. Thanks